# How to set font style for a text in array Zend PHP PDF functions

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, fonts

This is my array containing a text with other specs.

```
$name = $item->getName();
        $line[] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split(strip_tags($name), $maxChar, true, true),
            'feed' => 190,
            'font_size' => 9,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'height' => $lineHeight
        );
```

I want to assign a font style for it, say HELVETICA. How can it be done.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html#zend.pdf.drawing.using-fonts

Comment: I wanna assign it to a text from array. I dint user drawText. I'm unable to set font style for this as in normal way.